# SMTP error status 5.3.5 Email looping. Using Gmail

Tags: email, iis, smtp, gmail

I have a problem with SMTP configuration.

I use *Gmail* with my domain for ex. *www.mydomain.com*. When I try to send email from server under that domain to *mailbox@mydomain.com* I get fail report

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822;mailbox@mydomain.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.3.5
```

MX records are as in Google configuration wizard. Why is the mail looping?

```
10 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com  
10 aspmx.l.google.com.mydomain.com  
10 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com  
20 aspmx2.googlemail.com    
20 aspmx3.googlemail.com
```

My server is IIS 7, with default SMTP service.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If someone will find this question, problem was with DNS MX records:

```
aspmx.l.google.com.mydomain.com
```

but it should be

```
aspmx.l.google.com
```

Apparently this was causing the loop.